How to override Breezing Forms Bootstrap 5 quick mode CSS file?
The file in question is components/com_breezingforms/themes/quickmode_bootstrap5/system.css. It has some definitions with !important that I need to remove.
I found few potential ways to override it, but none of them worked:

create templates/[template]/css/com_breezingforms/themes/quickmode_bootstrap5/system.css file
create templates/[template]/css/theme/components/com_breezingforms/themes/quickmode_bootstrap5/system.css
custom CSS doesn't work because that !important is loaded after my importants due to JCH ordering. I could maybe try some more specific selectors but I'm trying to find a more optimal solution, if possible.

Is there any way to override such file?
